# How to implement repository pattern for multiple database

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, repository, s#arp-architecture, multiple-databases

We currently have two presentation projects (classic ASP and ASP.NET, which uses the "NHibernate Best Practices with ASP.NET" (predecessor or Sharp architecture). We are now rewrite all the classic ASP with Silverlight + WCF(maybe RIA services).

We have the following database architecture:
* one global data database - contains users and projects meta info
* each project has its own database to store project-specific info - same schema

We were able to hack a bit to make multiple databases work in ASP.NET because "NHibernate Best Practices with ASP.NET" uses DAO factories, which we can hack a bit to create the connection string - base on the projectId - to pass to the factory to create the corresponding NHibernate session.

For the rewrite, we would like to use the repository pattern from Sharp architecture. But we couldn't figure out how to do the similar hack...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ncommon framework](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon) which provides a nice foundation for multi-database support in NHibernate as explained in this [blog post](http://www.codeinsanity.com/2010/04/unit-of-work-implementation-in-ncommon.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have hacked a little bit to Sharp Architecture and re-built it for multiple database in [my post](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2011/01/21/a-first-look-at-conform-part-2.aspx). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what pattern you are using the ISessionFactory handles the connection. Use an IoC container with some form of named or optional parameters to specify the connection string.